# "Remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required" error when the application hit Rest API in C#

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, keystore, x509certificate2

I am trying to connect the production Rest API, the api url starts with "https://"

I have been told that i have to use the certificate to connect the API. When i try to connect the api without certificate i am getting error as

```
Error: The underlying connection was closed: could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel
```

I  have received the Key store file which is already using in java to connect the same production rest api.

With the help of KeyStore file how do i use in C#. Any help appreciate.

**Update:**
Now we were able to connect the Rest api with the help of below line in from local development environment.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
```

Now we deployed the code in Stage, Now we are receiving the below error

```
error      "Logging Error : System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: 
The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at
System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---One or more errors occurred."
```

Help me Please.

Comment: Did you try reading the error message?

Comment: yes, looks like the issue is proxy configuration in the IIS server, make whitelisting the IP address?

Comment: Sounds like you are inside a corporate firewall, with web access being mediated via an Http Proxy which requires Authenication. Pretty standard. You need to separately authenticate the Http proxy from the end point address. Look up the definition of a 407 error.

Comment: yes, we raised the ticket  in our organization to windows server team to add the IP address in the proxy exception list.